# Log4j Fileappender won't create the file where it should

Tags: java, logging, log4j, netbeans-7, fileappender

I'm trying to log into a html file using Log4j filappender. My properties file looks as follows

```
log = C:\Log
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/logfile.html

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.Title=log
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.LocationInfo=true
```

But it didn't create the logfile at C:\Log so I thought i didn't work at all but i found that it creates the logfile.html and the folder as well within my .netbeans folder (C:Users\Peter.netbeans\7.1.1\config\GF3\domain1\Log). I'm using Netbeans 7.1.1. I haven't used Log4j before and to be honest I have no idea why it does  this. Any ideas?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the line that is defining where to save the logfile:
`log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/logfile.html`

If you change that to
`log4j.appender.FILE.File=C:/log/logfile.html`
Then it might work.

AFAIK, the first line in your config `log = C:\Log` have no effect whatsoever. You can't use variables like that in your config file.

Answer (score 1):

The single backslash in your first line could be the problem:

log = C:\Log

Either use C:\Log or C:/Log.

I would write the path directly into

```
log4j.appender.FILE.File
```

without using the log = C:\Log